# zend module autoloading

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have developed a small application and now I want to create and administrator module. In the future I would like to add different modules but for now i would like to treat this admin as a module and to access it like http://host/module/controller

I have read about zend_autoloader and wrote this in my Bootstrap.php

```
protected function _initAutoload() {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'Admin',
            'basePath' => '/modules/admin'
        ));
```

I have created a default IndexController with the default index view file. When I try to access http://host/admin or http://host/admin/index i get an application error and of course the view is not loaded.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: An error occurred
Page not found

Comment: Just by searching Stack overflow for module loading issues, you get 200+ results. This is obviously a duplicate question.
ZF, just like any framework of any language, has a relatively steep learning curve. Do more research and studying before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone having the problem this guy sorts it out in the most newbish way possible.

http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-general-discussions-1/resources-developers-37/setup-multi-modules-zend-framework-v1-9-13-steps-3737.html

Comment: :) perfect. the most "codeigniter" approach to zend framework. Sometimes I wonder why zend developers won't just add something like that into zend quickstart instead of abstract this and interface that....:)